# Increment all records with fixed value in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to do this

```
User.all.each do |user|
    user.salary = user.salary + 100
    user.save
end
```

I tried this `User.update_all(salary: "salary + 100")` but it raised that exception `Mysql::Error: Incorrect integer value: 'salary + 100' for column 'salary' at row 1:`

What is the best way to increment all records in rails ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
User.update_all("salary = salary + 100")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do it like this:

`User.update_all('salary = salary + 100')`